# Passing the result of select to delete query

Tags: asp.net

I have a table

```
NAME   |   BONUS  
----------------
anil   |   40  
suresh |   25  
ramesh |   44  
anil   |   35  
anil   |   15
```

I want to delete the rows having `name = anil and bonus < max bonus of anil
OUTPUT`

```
anil   | 40
suresh | 25
ramesh | 44
```

I tried the query:

```
delete from table where name like 'anil' and bonus < (select max(bonus) 
from table where name like 'anil';
```

But its giving a syntax error. 
Can anyone help. I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ending parentheses for the subquery:

```
delete from table
where
  name like 'anil' and
  bonus < (select max(bonus) from table where name like 'anil'
```

should be

```
delete from table
where
  name like 'anil' and
  bonus < (select max(bonus) from table where name like 'anil')
```

Comment: It is already there and i am not getting that why you are make two times condition for check name like 'anil'

Comment: I'm getting this error! You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: @MayurDesai: The parenthesis is not there in the question. The condition with the name is twice because it's once in the subquery to get the highest value for that name, and once in the `delete` to only delete records with that name.

Comment: @user2298919: If your table is actually named `table` which is a keyword, then you need to use brackets around the name to specify that it's a name: `[table]`.

Comment: delete from [table] where name like 'anil' and bonus  NOT IN (select max(bonus) from [table] where name like 'anil' Group By name)

Please use above query.

Comment: @MayurDesai: No, please don't use that query. It will delete all record of all users, except those that has the exact same bonus value as the highest for the user `'anil'`. With the example data it would only leave one single record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Group by with aggregate function.

Check below query for the same.

```
delete from table where bonus < (select max(bonus) from table where name like 'anil' Group By name)
```

Comment: No, that's not needed. The grouping is implicit when you use the `max` aggregate and no `group by` clause, and the implicit grouping is one group containing all records, so the result is the same as what you suggest.

Comment: I'm getting this error!Error, You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: If you don't have the name in the condition for the delete, it will delete all records with a lower bonus value. In the example it would delete the `suresh` record also.

Comment: Yes, it should delete the suresh record also. But the point is, we can't specify target table for update in FROM clause. How to overcome this problem.

Comment: @user2298919: In your example you are showing that the suresh record is not deleted. Regarding that error, have you tried using brackets, as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The word 'table' is a reserved SQL keyword, which is what I think your error is referring to

> *You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause*

Comment: I have changed the name of the table. Not working. Giving the same error.

Comment: My query is, I want to delete the rows having name = anil and bonus < max bonus of anil.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear; what's the sql query with the changed name and closed parentheses, along with the error that it gives?